# Extending the inferred "this"

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a base prototype:

```
const proto = {
  const1: 1,
  const2: 2
}
```

Now somewhere I write another object that is supposed to have access to this base prototype. On the first attempt, it fails.

```
const consumer = {
  method1(): number {
    return this.const1 //const1 does no exist
  },
  method2() {
    return this.method1()
  }
}
```

Second try

```
//consumer is downcast to 'any' since it references itself
const consumer = {
  method1(this: typeof consumer & typeof proto): number {
    return this.const1
  },
  method2() {
    return this.method1()
  }
}
```

Is there any trick or way  of telling that the `this` parameter receives the current object plus an inherited prototype? (Preferrably not refactoring to classes)

Comment: `const consumer` doesn't say anything about having access to the base prototype... Why not use `class proto { const1: 1, const2: 2 } class consumer extends proto { method1(): number { return this.const1; } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with a simple variable, you will need an extra function to help with the inference and you will need to use the special `ThisType<T>` which will tell the compiler what `this` should be for any type defined inside the object literal:

```
const proto = {
    const1: 1,
    const2: 2
}


function extend<TBase, TCurrent>(base: TBase, current: TCurrent & ThisType<TCurrent & TBase>): TCurrent & TBase {
    return Object.assign(current, base);
}
const consumer = extend(proto, {
    method1(): number {
        return this.const1 //works
    },
    method2() {
        return this.method1()
    }
});
```

Comment: TYVM!!
I'm also bringing a more detailed issue related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51904568/communicating-types-between-static-and-instance-class-members-while-extending