# Communicating types between static and instance class members, while extending

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In the following example, I create a "bundle" which contains a react context AND a react class which renders a provider for this context. This "bundle" accepts some parameters, in this case expressed as (abstract) class properties to be overriden.

(could also use more functional patterns, i'm open to whatever pattern allows me to leverage the maximum possible of inference and extension)

The context is meant to be a "static-y" property, but its type depends on an instance property. I've been having difficulty on inferring the static context type from a type owned by the "instance side" of the class.

I ended up with a hack as described below, where the derived classes need to receive a `Self` type parameter and the context has to be accessed from `Derived.prototype.getContext()`. While this works, it is hacky, I'd like to know if I could avoid it.

```
type State<EntityType> = { hey: EntityType; ready: boolean }
abstract class CrudDetail<
  EntityType extends Object,
  Self extends CrudDetail<any, any>
> extends React.PureComponent<{}, State<EntityType>> {
  state = {
    ready: false,
    hey: {} as EntityType,
  }

  // exampĺes of possible parameters
  abstract entityName: string

  // this is meant to be overriden 
  // the context is tied on the instance state
  getContextValue() {
    return {
      hey: this.state.hey,
    }
  }

  // the type of this property depends on instance.getContextValue()
  // how can i access it from here?
  private static context = React.createContext({})

  // only instance members can access type parameters
  // so I came up with an instance member and a Self
  // type parameter to access the derived class type
  // This is kinda ugly and is the thing I'd like to avoid.
  getContext() {
    return (this.constructor as any).context as React.Context<ReturnType<Self['getContextValue']>>
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <CrudDetail.context.Provider value={this.getContextValue()}>
        {this.props.children}
      </CrudDetail.context.Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

consuming

```
type Person = { name: string }

class PersonCrud extends CrudDetail<Person, PersonCrud> {
  state = {
    ...super.state,
    name: "",
  }

  getContextValue = () => {
    let that = this
    return extend(super.getContextValue(), {
      name: this.state.name,
      heyreadyName() {
        return that.state.ready && this.hey && this.name
      },
    })
  }
}

const Test2 = () => {
  const Ctx = PersonCrud.prototype.getContext()
  return (
    <PersonCrud>
      <Ctx.Consumer>{ctx => <div>{ctx.heyreadyName()}</div>}</Ctx.Consumer>
    </PersonCrud>
  )
}
```

(`extend` comes from [Extending the inferred "this"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51900537/extending-the-inferred-this))

Reiterating, is it possible that I can:

- Establish a contract of parameters the base class needs to implement (either through classes, closures, or whatever)
- Have the contract implementations be type-safe
- Have the consuming context `<Context.Consumer>` correctly typed
- Be DRY. My approach still had the non-DRYness for needing to provide the `Self` type parameter, and the "this.constructor" hack

(i'd paste a codesandbox but infortunately it is still stuck on TS 2.7...)

Comment: I don't understand why you are using context at all; given that you have to pass the context down manually in `Test2`, it doesn't look any easier than using an ordinary prop.  Can you give a less trivial example?

Comment: I'm not questioning the use of context here, but the response is the standard: the consumer could be any levels deep, and by using it I avoid the need for several manual refactors on each prop/context signature change.

Answer (score 0):

The code below compiles for me, using a trick from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863#issuecomment-410887254).  I'm not sure you meant to make a single context and cast it to many different types; I've changed the code to make one context per subclass, and I'm sure you can change it back if you want.

```
function extend<TBase, TCurrent>(base: TBase, current: TCurrent & ThisType<TCurrent & TBase>): TCurrent & TBase {
  return Object.assign(current, base);
}

////////////////////

import * as React from "react";

type State<EntityType> = { hey: EntityType; ready: boolean }

type CrudDetailConstructor = typeof CrudDetail & {new (...args: any[]): any};

abstract class CrudDetail<
  EntityType extends Object,
> extends React.PureComponent<{}, State<EntityType>> {
  state = {
    ready: false,
    hey: {} as EntityType,
  }

  // exampĺes of possible parameters
  abstract entityName: string

  // this is meant to be overriden 
  // the context is tied on the instance state
  getContextValue() {
    return {
      hey: this.state.hey,
    }
  }

  // Declare here, although this will actually exist on the static side of each
  // concrete subclass.
  private static context?: React.Context<any>;

  public ["constructor"]: CrudDetailConstructor;

  static getContext<C extends CrudDetailConstructor>(this: C):
    React.Context<ReturnType<InstanceType<C>["getContextValue"]>> {
    return this.context || (this.context = React.createContext({} /*UNSOUND*/));
  }

  render() {
    let context = this.constructor.getContext();
    return (
      <context.Provider value={this.getContextValue()}>
        {this.props.children}
      </context.Provider>
    )
  }
}

////////////////////

type Person = { name: string }

class PersonCrud extends CrudDetail<Person> {
  entityName = "Person";
  state = {
    ...(this as CrudDetail<Person>).state,
    name: "",
  }

  getContextValue = () => {
    let that = this
    return extend(super.getContextValue(), {
      name: this.state.name,
      heyreadyName() {
        return that.state.ready && this.hey && this.name
      },
    })
  }
}

const Test2 = () => {
  const Ctx = PersonCrud.getContext()
  return (
    <PersonCrud>
      <Ctx.Consumer>{ctx => <div>{ctx.heyreadyName()}</div>}</Ctx.Consumer>
    </PersonCrud>
  )
}
```